# error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1 in angular making menu

Tags: angular

hi i want to make my menu to open and close when i click on it but i get this error

**> error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

> (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)">
>                                                      ~~~~~~
>
> src/app/layouts/default/default.component.ts:5:16
>       5   templateUrl: './default.component.html',
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       Error occurs in the template of component DefaultComponent.**

this is my default html code

```
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)"></app-header>


<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer mode="side" [opened]="sideBarOpen" >
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </mat-drawer>
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

this is my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-default',
  templateUrl: './default.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default.component.css']
})
export class DefaultComponent implements OnInit {

  sideBarOpen =true;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  sideBarToggler() {
    this.sideBarOpen = !this.sideBarOpen;
  }
}
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: Remove `$event` from `(toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler($event)"`

Answer (score 0):

no arguments expected in the code

```
sideBarToggler() {
  this.sideBarOpen = !this.sideBarOpen;
}
```

while the argument is passed in the template

```
sideBarToggler($event)
```

the solution would be either declare the argument

```
sideBarToggler(event: Event) {
  this.sideBarOpen = !this.sideBarOpen;
}
```

or don't pass it in the template

```
<app-header (toggleSideBarForMe)="sideBarToggler()"></app-header>
```